# Uncheck other checkbox on one checked but checked mark not remove

Tags: jquery, css

[image]

I have two checkbox, when I click on 1st div featured playlist checkbox another popular genre should be uncheck.but it not happens, only value changed but checked mark not changed. can anyone help me, to solve this issue.

**HTML**

```
@foreach ($popular as $genreTag)
    <li class="lib">
        <label><input class="genreTag"  id="{{ $genreTag->id}}" type="checkbox" name="" value="{{ $genreTag->name }}">{{{ $genreTag->name }}} ({{count(json_decode($genreTag->tracks, true))}}) </label>
    </li>
@endforeach

@foreach ($featured as $playlist)
    <li class="lib">
        <label><input class="filter-playlist" id='{{{ $playlist->id}}}' tracks='{{ $playlist->tracks }}' type="checkbox" value="{{ $playlist->name}}">{{ $playlist->name}} ({{count(json_decode($playlist->tracks, true))}}) </label>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

**JS**

```
$('.genreTag').on('change', function (e){
    $('input.filter-playlist').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});

$('.filter-playlist').on('change', function (e) {
    $('input.genreTag').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

**CSS**

```
.chk-area {
    border: 2px solid #d22890;
    margin: -2px 10px 0 0;
    float: left;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    position: relative;
}
.chk-checked {
    background: #d22890;
    border-color: #fff;
}
.chk-unchecked {
    background: #fff;
    border-color: #d22890;
}
.ch-playlist {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    color: #667482;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 45px;
}
```

Comment: Do you have integrated some checkbox plugin?

Comment: ohk wait a minutes

Comment: @romil checkbox used for multiple selections if you want anyone of the select boxes then use input type radio

Comment: @MehdiDehghani check now sir, on answer

Comment: hi press f12 and place a break point ,then in which selector is not working convey.So can identified

Comment: @MehrajKhan hello sir, i know checkbox is used for multiple selection but i have two div , and i want only one current div checkbox should be checked, when and checked another div it will unchecked 1 st div checkboxes.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani yes sir , i remove .not(this) but didint get any result, the problem is still same

Comment: @LDS hello sir, i tried but everything is workking fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JS code is okay. you don't need to use `not(this)` tho, because you bind `change` event based on class name.

After sending more details about the generated HTML, this is the final solution.

```
var $genreTags = $('input.genreTag'),
    $filterPlaylist = $('input.filter-playlist');

$genreTags.on('change', function (e){
    $filterPlaylist.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.prop('checked', false);
        // because of generated html
        $this.parent().find('> div').removeClass('chk-checked').addClass('chk-unchecked');
    });
});

$filterPlaylist.on('change', function (e) {
    $genreTags.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.prop('checked', false);
        // because of generated html
        $this.parent().find('> div').removeClass('chk-checked').addClass('chk-unchecked');
    });
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60964095/convert-audio-to-a-tag-in-core-php   can you please help me to solve this.

Comment: @iAmGroot I answered your question, https://stackoverflow.com/a/60964870/3367974

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine. But it's better to use input type radio if you want to choose any one of the options. I prepared the sample code

```css
$('input:radio').click(function() {
  $('input:radio:checked').addClass('active');
  $('input:radio:not(:checked)').removeClass('active');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="radio1">
  </label>


<label>
     <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="radio2">
   </label>
```

Comment: sir your 1 st answer is good, my problem is, when i checked on 2nd the 1st chekbox is noty remove. i think this issue is from jcf plugin

Answer (score 0):

Try using Radio button on parent div i.e. in your case featured-playlist , on particular radio button click change , un-check all the Popular-genre checkbox