# Convert [audio ] to <a> tag in core php

Tags: php

### I am in trouble while converting a link to tag . here is

I am trying

```
[audio mp3="https://abcd.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2020/03/classical-demo.mp3"][/audio]
```

to convert

```
<a href="https://abcd.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2020/03/classical-demo.mp3"></a>
```

I am use `str_replace`, following are the code one by one.

```
$a = '[audio mp3="https://abcd.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2020/03/classical-demo.mp3"][/audio]';

echo str_replace("[","<",$a);
echo str_replace("]",">",$a);
echo str_replace("audio","a",$a);
echo str_replace("mp3","href",$a);
exit();
```

But still getting no result.

Is any another way for solving this? any one having solution for this please help me to solve out this problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm C# developer not PHP, the code seems okay tho. what is the result of your code?

Comment: If that's your actual code, you're discarding every replacement after doing them.

Comment: Careful with that last replacement, you'll change your file extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not `PHP` developer, but I think you can use following code:

```php
$a = '[audio mp3="https://abcd.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2020/03/classical-demo.mp3"][/audio]';

$b = str_replace("[","<", $a);
$b = str_replace("]",">", $b);
$b = str_replace("audio","a", $b);
// you need to replace mp3=, not mp3, as you have 2 of it
$b = str_replace("mp3=","href=", $b);

// optional
$b = str_replace("><",">link text<", $b);

echo $b;
exit();
```

`$b` will be: `<a href="https://abcd.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2020/03/classical-demo.mp3">link text</a>`

[See it in action](https://3v4l.org/l4lcR) *thanks to @Phil*

Comment: great sir..... its great method ty so much and @phil you too.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are running replace on `$a` without updating it, so you function replaces `<` with `[` and outputs, then it replaces `>` with `]` but on the original variable, then outputs.

If you update the variable with the result of `str_replace` it works as intended.

```
$a = '[audio mp3="https://abcd.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2020/03/classical-demo.mp3"][/audio]';

$a = str_replace("[","<",$a);
$a = str_replace("]",">",$a);
$a = str_replace("audio","a",$a);
$a = str_replace("mp3=","href=",$a);
echo $a;
```

### Edit

Also as @Phil pointed out in a comment your last line will change your file extension, I adjusted the last replace to account for this.

Answer (score 1):

As alternative, to `str_replace`, perhaps you could use regex?

```php
$x = '[audio mp3="https://abcd.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2020/03/classical-demo.mp3"][/audio]';

preg_match('/"(.*?)"/', $x, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

output

```
Array
(
    [0] => "https://abcd.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2020/03/classical-demo.mp3"
    [1] => https://abcd.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2020/03/classical-demo.mp3
)
```